# Do you have to pay off each loan all at once (not including the down payment)?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I just got my full house so I owe 38,900 bells. (I know you have to pay the original down payment at once.) I keep trying to pay off a little bit and it isn't reacting. I accidentally paid off 900 bells and I just lost them. The owed amount stayed the same.

I saved and quit and went back in immediately. Same thing.

I also saved and quit the game completely and restarted and still the same thing.

It might just be a visual issue. My loan is getting paid off but I just can't see any progress but I don't want to risk my measly 12,000 bells to test it and I also don't have enough to try paying it off all at once at the moment to see if it will work at all.

Does anybody know how to fix this if it is a bug or if I am just supposed to pay off every loan in full every time and they just don't tell you?

**Update:**

It turns out the original loan amount is 39,800 bells. So my 900 bells did go through. What I was expecting was the "Pay Loan" screen to function like the deposit and withdraw screen.

The Deposit menu updates your Held Bells value to reflect the amount of bells you will have left if you make the deposit and your Account bells to the amount that will be in your bank if you make that deposit. The Withdraw screen does the same in the opposite direction of course.

The repay loan menu does not do this (at least for me, which may be a bug in itself but a much less worrying one). As you can see in the linked pictures. When I put in [400 bells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9D8R.jpg) My held bells and bells owed stay the same as when I put in [4000 bells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FF32P.jpg).

So coupled with that and me not noticing the switch between the 8 and 9 I thought I couldn't pay off my loan.

Comment: You are not required to pay the loan all at once.  This sounds very unusual.  Are you sure you're in the "Pay Loan" option, and not the "Deposit" option?  Can you take some screenshots of the problem and edit your question to include them?  Use the L & R bumpers on your 3DS to snap a picture of your top screen, and you can either remove your SD card for use in your computer or upload photos from your 3DS web browser to i.nintendo.net.

Comment: I'm an idiot. >< For whatever reason the loan amount is not updating WHILE inputting bells (which may or may not be a problem in itself). I will upload pictures of what I thought was my problem in a second. The original loan amount was 39,800. So my 900 went through but because only the 8 and 9 flipped and it did not update while inputting the number 900 I thought it didn't go through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to pay the loan off all at once, and infact the loans will quickly exceed what you are even capable of holding on your person out of item form very quickly (You are capped at around 100,000 bells before you have to put them into the bank machine or bags of bells).

Comment: You can still pay 100k+ bell loans off at once, you can pay or deposit bells from inside bags of bells too.

Comment: @BenBrocka Ah, good to know it accepts the items from your inventory as well. Does that let you hold some of the upper cost ranges when it gets to around 500,000??? I am actually annoyed that it can not just deduct it from my deposited balance :/

Comment: You can just withdraw your whole deposited amount in one go (I think, you can certainly deposit all in one go). And yeah you can hold 16(?) bags of 99 at the same time plus your inventory so you can pay off over a million all at once